# EXCEL - #VALUE on INDIRECT

Tags: excel

I'm getting a `#VALUE` error on an `INDIRECT()` and can't figure out why. I've never used this function before, so I'd appreciate some pointers.

I'm constructing a string in a cell. The constructed string has a value of the form `[items.xls]items!$A$1:$F$30`.

For purposes of this question, suppose the constructed string is in cell `$A$1` of `Sheet1` in `workbook1.xls`. in cell `$B$1`, I have `=INDIRECT(A1)`, which I'd hoped would create the actual reference constructed using cell `$A$1` so I could use the reference in a `VLOOKUP()`, but I can't get that far because of the `#VALUE` error.

I have the workbook `items.xls` open in excel at the same time as `workbook1.xls`.

the spreadsheet `items` exists in `workbook1`.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It has little to do with the `INDIRECT` function. I dare say if you just entered `=[items.xls]items!$A$1:$F$30` in some cell you'd see the same result.  Your reference is returning an array.  To return a single item out of that array to use in `VLOOKUP` you could embed it into an `INDEX` function.

Comment: Oh, and to use it for the array argument, just use it as is as the `table_array` argument.

Comment: yes, actually i first tried it w/the whole expression including the vlookup, which as you've pointed out, requires an array as an argument. that's when i got the #value error. in trying to isolate the problem, i successively whittled the expression down until i had only the indirect.

Comment: You are not providing enough information for me to speculate further. I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question to provide all of the information we need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because your reference in cell $A$1 is to a range of cells (and not just one cell), you need enter your `=Indirect(A1)` formula as an array formula.

Select range `Sheet1!$B$1:$G$30`.  30 rows, 6 columns; the same size as `[items.xls]items!$A$1:$F$30`.

Type your formula `=INDIRECT(A1)` into the formula bar. Instead of pressing Enter, ***press Ctrl+Shift+Enter*** to complete your formula.

The formula should look like `{=INDIRECT(A1)}` in the cell.

Check that none of the cells in range `[items.xls]items!$A$1:$F$30` has a #VALUE error.  If they do, that error will show on your new sheet as well.

Also double-check your formula that constructs the string in cell A1.  If part of that formula is returning a #VALUE error, it will pass it on to the `INDIRECT()` formula.

You can highlight parts of your formula in the formula bar and press F9 to evaluate just that part of the formula.  Just remember to hit ESC to exit the cell afterward.

Another alternative is the Evaluate Formula option on the Formulas part of the Excel ribbon menu.

Comment: @david, note that when you go on and create the `VLOOKUP` formula, you won't need the array formula.  eg `=VLOOKUP(B1,INDIRECT(A1),2,0)`